# How do you install libvirt 4.0 on ubuntu16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, libvirt

In general, how would one go about doing something like that? I need the libvirt version that comes with ubuntu 18.04. I am not ready to upgrade my whole OS. Is there a way to just install this piece and upgrade its dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need libvirt 4.0, then you'll have to build it from source. Attempting to add the repos from Ubuntu 18.04 isn't a good idea because it can trap you in dependency hell or otherwise break your system.

You can get the source code from Github: https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/releases
You might have to build other dependencies from source as well because later versions may be needed than what's on Ubuntu 16.04.